# How can I combine this sql where clause to use one Select?

Tags: sql, t-sql

So if you look at the last `WHERE` clause.  `Where inv_location_id in` One of them I am using an `integer` and the other is a `set`.

How can I combine these?

```
IF ( @inventory_location_id = NULL )
    SELECT  clinic_desc ,
            dbo.fn_get_clinic_address_formatted(@application_name,
                                                clinic_id, NULL, NULL,
                                                'STANDARD', NULL, NULL,
                                                NULL, NULL) AS formatted_address ,
            vfc_pin ,
            contact ,
            email_address ,
            phone ,
            fax
    FROM    dbo.clinics
    WHERE   clinic_id IN (
            SELECT  clinic_id
            FROM    dbo.clinic_inv_locations
            WHERE   inv_location_id IN (
                    SELECT  ilr.clinic_id
                    FROM    dbo.inv_location_reconciliation ilr
                    WHERE   inv_location_reconciliation_id = @reconciliation_id ) )

ELSE
    SELECT  clinic_desc ,
            dbo.fn_get_clinic_address_formatted(@application_name,
                                                clinic_id, NULL, NULL,
                                                'STANDARD', NULL, NULL,
                                                NULL, NULL) AS formatted_address ,
            vfc_pin ,
            contact ,
            email_address ,
            phone ,
            fax
    FROM    dbo.clinics
    WHERE   clinic_id IN (
            SELECT  clinic_id
            FROM    dbo.clinic_inv_locations
            WHERE   inv_location_id IN ( @inventory_location_id ) )
```

Comment: Please review the following joining methods
http://www.georeference.org/doc/queries_using_multiple_tables.htm

Comment: 90% of your code is irrelevant to the problem. Please reduce the SQL to the minimum so we don't have to wade through your whole query. See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). And format it properly.

Comment: Yea and I don't have time to read 90% of that webpage, and the error was actually in the first line. So thanks but I figured it out.

Comment: I notice you use `IN()` to apply the `@inventory_location_id` parameter. Is there a particular reason you don't just use `=` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the where to be

```
WHERE (
    (
        @inventory_location_id IS NULL AND (
            inv_location_id IN (
            SELECT  ilr.clinic_id
            FROM    dbo.inv_location_reconciliation ilr
            WHERE   inv_location_reconciliation_id = @reconciliation_id )
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        @inventory_location_id IS NOT NULL AND (
            inv_location_id IN ( @inventory_location_id )
        )
    )
)
```

It can be made more concise, but I left it big and wordy for clarity here :)

Comment: Yes except shouldn't you use `is null` and `is not null`?

Comment: Haha, derp, good catch. I've had my head in C# all day, where you just use the plain old equality operator for `null` :)

Comment: Also there's a stray NULL in the second part of the expression.

Comment: Good grief. I wish my QA team was as good as you ;) Both fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I like CTEs with complicated queries because I think it makes them easier to read, so I would do something like below.  There are many other ways to solve this problem and I don't claim this is the the fastest.

*I haven't tested it so proceed with caution*

```
with clinic_list AS
(
    SELECT  ilr.clinic_id as clinic_id  
    FROM    dbo.inv_location_reconciliation ilr
    WHERE   inv_location_reconciliation_id = @reconciliation_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  clinic_id
    FROM    dbo.clinic_inv_locations
    WHERE   inv_location_id IN ( @inventory_location_id ) 
)
    SELECT  clinic_desc ,
            dbo.fn_get_clinic_address_formatted(@application_name,
                                                clinic_id, NULL, NULL,
                                                'STANDARD', NULL, NULL,
                                                NULL, NULL) AS formatted_address ,
            vfc_pin ,
            contact ,
            email_address ,
            phone ,
            fax
    FROM    dbo.clinics
    WHERE   clinic_id IN (SELECT  clinic_id FROM    clinic_list)
```

I also have a strong **suspicion** that using a function here is the wrong choice.  Functions are quite horrible in SQL and are often the cause of bad performance and scaling.

Comment: Yeah the rows returned should always be less then 50. So I am not too worried about it. I had some funk with the with.  But no biggie I had a pretty good solution but I broke it down to the most basic I could thinking I would find some flaw in my coding choice.  But I forgot that you can't use = NULL.  Once I changed it to IS NULL I got what I needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (clinic_id INT )
IF(@reconciliation_id IS NOT NULL)
  INSERT INTO @temp SELECT ilr.clinic_id 
                    FROM dbo.inv_location_reconciliation ilr 
                    WHERE inv_location_reconciliation_id =@reconciliation_id
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @temp (clinic_id) VALUES (@inventory_location_id)
SELECT clinic_desc, dbo.fn_get_clinic_address_formatted(@application_name, clinic_id,      NULL, NULL, 'STANDARD', null,NULL, NULL, NULL) AS formatted_address,vfc_pin, contact, email_address, phone, fax 
FROM dbo.clinics 
WHERE clinic_id IN (SELECT clinic_id 
                    FROM dbo.clinic_inv_locations 
                    WHERE inv_location_id in (SELECT clinic_id FROM @temp))
```

Comment: A table variable seems like total overkill for solving this problem.

Comment: Yeah I am kinda new to using sql. Most if not all of my experience is in C#. So I am still trying to learn.